# How should I make my icons as a part of a design system?

Tags: sketch-app, icon, interface-design

I'm creating a design system for a user interface design project and I want to make icons accessible for designers and developers. Icons can have different styles like:

- Different strokes (1px and 2px)
- Different colors
- Different sizes (24x24, 32x32, 64x64 and etc.)

I know that all of the icons should be pixel perfect. what is the best practice for managing icons in a design system? should it be stroked or offset based? I'm using Sketch to design user interfaces. Is it a way to prepare icons the above styles and also be pixel perfect?

Answer (score 1):

I am sure that many design systems have avoided having to create multiple sets of pixel perfect icons by using svg files or implementing font icons so that the size can be scaled consistently and managed much more efficiently.

If you look into the use of design tokens in design systems, you will also see that these are common problems that there are known or established solutions for in most of the recent and well-established design systems like Material Design, Microsoft Fluent, Apple HIG, IBM Carbon, etc.